# Angular Material unit tests - Failed to find MatHarness element

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for my app which uses Angular Material.

I wanna make sure that there's a material card in the page. For this, I use the following code:

```
  let loader: HarnessLoader;
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let authService: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    authService = jasmine.createSpyObj<AuthService>(['authenticate', 'logout']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: authService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   it('should display a material card', async () => {
    const card = await loader.getHarness(MatCardHarness);
    expect(card).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

But, this returns the error:

```
Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
        (MatCardHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-card")
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<mat-card class="custom-class">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
</mat-card>
```

I'll be able to solve this by adding `mat-card` class to the `<mat-card>` element. But isn't it supposed to work without manually adding the class? Is there anything wrong with the way I set up my tests?

Comment: Did you make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Try importing MatCardModule into you TestBed configuration.

```
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule,
      MatCardModule,
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: authService }]
  }).compileComponents();
});
```